# Unwanted coding shown next to inserted images on PDF, have no idea why? Pictures and code shown in description

Tags: graphics, code, coding

[image: Unwanted code shown here.]

Have this problem for all images except this one:

[image]

I have tried PNG and Jpeg files, same problem.

Here is the code us for the "count final.jpg"

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=15cm]{box count final.jpg}
\caption{Box Count Diagrams for Illustrative Purposes}
\label{fig:box counting}
\end{figure}
```

And here is the code of the Cantor Set image:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{cantor.png}
\caption{The Cantor Set}
\label{fig:cantor}
\end{figure}
```

Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated, been having this problem for months.

Comment: Use the grffile package, or better: don't use spaces in file names.

Comment: no spaces worked like a charm, thank you very much!